# Undefined variable: token (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\myclassicbook\resources\views\users\pages\reset.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am using laravel 5.8 auth classes in custom, I have created my custom forgot page and it sent email and I got email in mailtrap.io but when I click on Reset Password button it show an error
Undefined variable: token (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\myclassicbook\resources\views\users\pages\reset.blade.php)

Comment: The message is pretty clear. Show us `reset.blade.php`, and where `$token` is defined and passed to the view in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email password reset route uses showResetForm method on ResetPasswordController.

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
```

It will help you

Answer (score -1):

Please ensure that the following line exist in reset.blade.php 
`<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">`

I hope it help you.

Comment: OP's issue is that `$token` is undefined. Adding these lines wouldn't fix that.